# Illegal characters in path when loading a string with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0

I have very simple XML in a string that I'm trying to load via `XDocument` so that I can use LINQ to XML:

```
 var xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
 <person>Test Person</person>";

 var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlString); //'Illegal characters in path' error thrown here
```

I get an `Illegal characters in path.` error thrown when I try to load the XML; could someone please explain why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You are looking for `XDocument.Parse` - `XDocument.Load` is for *files* not xml strings:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

Comment: and for `XmlDocument` it's `XmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString)`

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for XML String

```
        XDocument reader;
        using (StringReader s = new StringReader(**XmlResult**))
        {
            reader = XDocument.Load(s);
        }
```